# How to improve Regression RMSE with LightGBM

Tags: python, regression, pandas, lightgbm

I have the following dataset:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Joffreybvn/real-estate-data-analysis/master/data/clean/belgium_real_estate.csv

I want to predict the price column, based on the other features, basically I want to predict house price based on square meters, number of rooms, postal code, etc.

So I did the following:

Load data:

```
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='BelgiumRealEstate')
data  =dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()

data.sample(5)


Column1 postal_code city_name   type_of_property    price   number_of_rooms house_area  fully_equipped_kitchen  open_fire   terrace garden  surface_of_the_land number_of_facades   swimming_pool   state_of_the_building   lattitude   longitude   province    region
33580   33580   9850    Landegem    1   380000  3   127 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   as new  3.588809    51.054637   Flandre-Orientale   Flandre
11576   11576   9000    Gent    1   319000  2   89  1   0   1   0   0   2   0   as new  3.714155    51.039713   Flandre-Orientale   Flandre
12830   12830   3300    Bost    0   170000  3   140 1   0   1   1   160 2   0   to renovate 4.933924    50.784632   Brabant flamand Flandre
20736   20736   6880    Cugnon  0   270000  4   218 0   0   0   0   3000    4   0   unknown 5.203308    49.802043   Luxembourg  Wallonie
11416   11416   9000    Gent    0   875000  6   232 1   0   0   1   0   2   0   good    3.714155    51.039713   Flandre-Orientale   Flandre
```

I hot encoded the category features, city, province, region, state of the building:

```
one_hot_state_of_the_building=pd.get_dummies(data.state_of_the_building) 
one_hot_city = pd.get_dummies(data.city_name, prefix='city')
one_hot_province = pd.get_dummies(data.province, prefix='province')
one_hot_region=pd.get_dummies(data.region, prefix ="region")
```

Then I added those columns to the pandas dataframe

```
#removing categorical features 
data.drop(['city_name','state_of_the_building','province','region'],axis=1,inplace=True) 
 

#Merging one hot encoded features with our dataset 'data' 
data=pd.concat([data,one_hot_city,one_hot_state_of_the_building,one_hot_province,one_hot_region],axis=1)
```

I remove the price

```
x=data.drop('price',axis=1) 
y=data.price
```

then train test split

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.3)
```

then I train:

```
x_df = DataFrame(x, columns= data.columns)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_df, y, test_size=0.15)

#Converting the data into proper LGB Dataset Format
d_train=lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)


#Declaring the parameters
params = {
    'task': 'train', 
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'num_leaves': 10,
    'learnnig_rate': 0.05,
    'metric': {'l2','l1'},
    'verbose': -1
}
#model creation and training
clf=lgb.train(params,d_train,10000)
#model prediction on X_test
y_pred=clf.predict(x_test)
#using RMSE error metric
mean_squared_error(y_pred,y_test)
```

However the RMSE its:
6053845952.2186775

which seems a huge number.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean_squared_error(y_pred,y_test)` is MSE, not RMSE (which would be `mse ** 0.5`). Taking a square root of it yields around 80k, which is not that huge compared to your actual price values - you seem to have around 75% explained variance, which is quite decent.

You can probably improve it further by performing some EDA and dealing with outliers somehow (MSE is outlier sensitive). You should also check for possible highly correlated features, as those inflate you model variance (at a quick glance, you don't use `drop_first` when doing OHE, thus getting redundant columns).

Scaling is not really a must, tree models, including gradient boosting on trees, are rather indifferent to scale.

Answer (score 0):

You must normalize data of features before feeding into model. Your data has features with white range of values. You can use minmax or normalization.